# How can I solve the inability to achieve fragment jump through onclick？

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, buttonclick

The program did not report any errors, but when I **clicked the button** to jump to the fragment, the program **crashed directly** and still did not report any errors.

**This is MainActicity code:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }

    public void selectFragment(View view) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                fragment = new testFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                fragment = new secTestFragment();
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + view.getId());
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

This is my main activity layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="267dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
        android:onClick="selectFragment"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.663" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="186dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="137dp"
        android:text="textButton"
        android:onClick="selectFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmenttest.testFragment"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="411dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the first fragment page layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".testFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:src="@drawable/burwood"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the second fragment page layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".secTestFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I hope can get some suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to debug your application and you can set a breakpoint before it crashes. Then step over the crash and you should se the crash in the debug console or in the `logcat` output. If for some reason they are not there, you can run `adb logcat` in the terminal and watch the output as you run your application and it will log the crash there.

Logcat tool in Android Studio
[image: logcat tool]

You can find more information on command-line logcat https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat